# Can't resolve rxjs/operators while using ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to incorporate ngx-datatable in my Angular-2 application. I followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/getting-started) but I am getting the following error:

> ERROR in ./~/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operators' in 'C:\Myproject\node_modules\@swimlane\ngx-datatable\release'
>        @ ./~/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.js 8:136-161
>        @ ./ClientApp/app/app.shared.module.ts
>        @ ./ClientApp/app/app.server.module.ts
>        @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs":  "^5.5.5",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^12.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^5.0.0",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "raven-js": "^3.24.2"
  }
}
```

As you can see, it already has the rxjs reference. So, I am really not sure what else to do to fix this issue. If there is any other file you want me to show you then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The ngx-datatable version 12.0.0 was update to work with angular 6. Angular 6 is now working with rxjs >6 (see [this blogpost](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4)), which means the ngx-datatable probably is also working with rxjs >6 (see [this issue](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1395)). You are still referencing rxjs 5.5.0 which is a bit different in terms of imports, this is probably why ngx-datatable (that needs rxjs 6) can't find the stuff it needs in the rxjs 5.5.0 folder (I think rxjs/operators does not exist anymore in rxjs 6).

So in order to make things work you probably have to downgrade to a lower version of ngx-datatable that still works with rxjs 5.5.0 or, which I would highly recommend, update your angular version and rxjs version to version 6. This of course probably triggers some more errors, but in the long term run, this should be the way to go.

Comment: What commands do I need to run in order to update angular and rxjs?

Comment: I usually set the numbers manually in the package.json file and then run `npm upgrade` I think. There are other ways to do this, angular brought a new tool for updating dependencies, but I'm not familiar with how it works

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in a very different context. I tried quite a few things before finding this:

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

Seems like I needed a very recent rxjs in general, but also an rxjs compatibility layer after installing something that upgraded other node libraries.